# remote_ip is returning an ip different from whatismyip.com in some cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ip-address

I am trying to set up some IP whitelisting for a specific controller and I'm relying on the value returned by `request.remote_ip`

```
def country_whitelist
  request_country = Custom::BackofficeLibrary.get_country_by_ip(request.remote_ip)
  head 404 unless ['PE'].include? request_country
end
```

My problem is that for certain devices/networks, the IP address returned by `request.remote_ip` is wrong.

Using my phone's mobile network for example, I'm getting an IP for the US when I'm located in Peru. However, if I browse on my phone to http://www.whatismyip.com or to http://freegeoip.net I do get the correct Peru IP address.

So in some cases (1 in 10), remote_ip is failing to get the correct ip when free internet services get it right.

My setup is AWS EC2 -> Nginx -> Puma -> Rails 5.0.0.1

I have tried AWS with and without a load balancer in front and it makes no difference.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Adding Ngnix partial config in case it's relevant:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  root /home/deploy/backoffice/current/public;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection '';
    proxy_pass http://app;
  }
```